# How can I parse this string into a searchable object?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel.  I'm getting values from a service that always have an XML header.  The actual XML hierarchy structure is unknown.  It could be different each call.  I want to be able to read in the actual data (ignoring the header) and have it so that I can use some sort of query language available in C# (linq, XMLDoc, ???)

So given string **myXML** which could contain either of the following (or other) XML documents, how would I search for the existence of **cycleEndTime**

```XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SubscriptionResponse>
  <SID>uuid:41</SID>
  <duration>0</duration>
</SubscriptionResponse>
```

or I might get something like this:

```XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event seqnum="162" sid="uuid:43">
  <control>_22</control>
  <action>1</action>
  <node></node>
  <eventInfo>
    <totalCostToday>0.000000</totalCostToday>
    <totalCostPeriod>0.000000</totalCostPeriod>
    <totalUsagePeriod>0.000000</totalUsagePeriod>
    <cycleEndTime>2017/01/15 14:30:30</cycleEndTime>
  </eventInfo>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load it  as `XmlDocument` and look for specific node:

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(text);
var result = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("cycleEndTime");
if (result.Count == 1)
{
    var time = result.Item(0).FirstChild.InnerText;
}
```

In case of your second xml you will find one, for the first xml, count will be 0.

Or the same thing with `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(text);
var result = xDoc.Descendants("cycleEndTime").FirstOrDefault();
if (result != null)
{
    var time = result.Value;
}
```